# None can be covered

Tags: mathematics

Is it possible (not logistically, but theoretically) to make 2017 rugs such that no rug can be completely covered by the others (where overlap is allowed)?

Another way to think about it: You make 2017 rugs. Then your friend takes any rug and tries to cover it with the other 2016 rugs. (overlap allowed) If he can do it then he wins, otherwise you win. Is it possible for you to win?

---

**Disclaimer:** this is not my question, I found it on a maths handout I got somewhere

Comment: Er just place them all on the floor no overlapping? Not sure I understand

Comment: ...or on the walls and ceiling, or each one in a different room to make sure

Comment: ok I will edit the question for more clarity

Comment: I still don't get it. You just place them all really far apart

Comment: Yes, but suppose the first rug is size 2x1 and the second is size 2x1, and the third is size 2x2. Then the 3rd rug can be covered by rugs 1&2 because we put them side by side on the 3rd rug. It shouldn't matter how far apart the rugs are.

Comment: But since you can place them anywhere, they can be any size, just say they are all infinitely far away from each other

Comment: Ok think about it this way. You make 2017 rugs. Then your friend takes any rug and tries to cover it with the other 2016 rugs. If he can then he wins, otherwise you win. Is it possible for you to win?

Comment: @Wen1now you should clarify that. Exactly how you just said it makes the most sense.

Comment: Ok I'll add that to the question.

Comment: This is still very confusing. Your friend tries to cover it with the other 2016 rugs? You can win by making the first rug larger than the sum of all the other 2016 rugs?

Comment: Then your friend can just choose to try and cover the second rug

Comment: I believe it is "no rug can be completely covered by all the others".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

> Start simply with 3 rugs.  Make them $4\times4$, $8\times2$, and $16\times1$ in size.  There is no way to fully cover any of them with any combination of the other two.
>  Extending to 4 rugs, you need $1\times64$, $2\times32$, $4\times16$, and $8\times8$.  The pattern emerges.
>
>  To get it to work for 2017 rugs, you'd end up with some rather unwieldy sized rugs.  Specifically, their lengths would be $2^0 ... 2^{2016}$ and their widths would be $2^{2016\times 2} ... 2^{2016}$.
>  Or, generalized, $(2^0 ... 2^{(n-1)}) \times (2^{(n-1) \times 2} ... 2^{(n-1)})$.

Comment: Whoops. Thanks for the edit, you're correct :)